# iOS Different Views for Table View Cell items

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I just started iOS development last week and I am creating a Table View based application. I having trouble understanding how to use storyboard.

I want each Table Cell to open a different ViewController.

[image]

Currently it is setup like this: 
[image]

Then in the Component View Controller I use if/else statements to determine what content to load. The problem occurs when one of the views needed a TabBar.

How do I assign different View Controllers to each individual cell, rather than one "template" view and forced to add everything dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I will say that it probably isn't the best idea to assign an individual view per cell. However, if it is what you wish to do, then so be it.

1. What you would do is create a segue from the table view to the new view by clicking on the table view icon and dragging a segue like so:

[image]

2.You would give that segue an identifier like "embedTweetsSegue" or something.

You can then check for the cell being touched and perform the segue programmatically using:

```
 performSegueWithIdentifier("embedTweetsSegue", sender: self)
```

Comment: Very cool. Thank you. What is best practice when it comes to lets say, one of the cells opens a View that has a Tab Bar View but not all of them have Tab Bar View.